# Send e-mails to focused inbox using EmailOperator in Python-DAG

Tags: python, email

**Requirement :** To send e-mails based on some business conditions.

I am using a DAG to automate my process in Apache Airflow.

**Approach :** To achieve my requirement I am using EmailOperator in my Python code.

**Issue :** But for some reasons, the e-mails are getting delivered to the recipient's junk folder instead of inbox folder.

```
EmailOperator(task_id='send_emails', to='abc@testmail.com',
                       subject='This is my mail subject'
                       html_content=" <p>Hi,<br><br>My content<br> <br> Thanks",
                       files=attachment, dag=dag)
```

Any suggestions or help is appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

**Solution**:
recipient should configure is email client not to move emails that are coming from "you" to junk folder.

Note that I have removed most of the tags since they are not relevant to the problem.

Comment: Is there any possibilities to deliver the e-mail to focused inbox from python?

Comment: No. You cant control the behavior of the email client.

Comment: Okay fine. Thank you for the response.

Comment: This is a bad answer. It's not how it works.

Comment: @JarekPotiuk Can you explain "how it works.."?

Comment: Yes. I answered it above.

Answer (score -1):

For the start, You need to configure Airflow to use your SMTP relay server (and your server needs to be properly configured):

https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/howto/email-config.html

You likely do not have your system configured to send emails via your authenticated domain. You need to have a domain registered and mail server configured properly to authenticate yours requests and Airflow should be configured to make use of this server.

Also your mail server should be properly configured as well to confirm that you are authorized to send emails. Example thread about it here:

https://serverfault.com/questions/48428/how-to-send-emails-and-avoid-them-being-classified-as-spam